# VBA macro - copying >4.000 workbooks in loop consumes > 1,5 GB RAM

Tags: excel, vba, memory, powerquery

beforehand, I am quite ok with coding but far far away of being a pro.

My macro aggregates all workbooks in a subfolder into one sheet.
The range copies via formula from the closed workbook is a range "A3:AOO10" so quite large.

The subfolders I retrieve and loop through via:

```
For Each dFolder In fso.GetFolder(contractFolderPath).SubFolders
```

Going forward it is then looping:

```
 For Each cFile In dFolder.Files
```

followed by a few checks to exclude unwanted (non-excel) files also stored in the subfolders.

Following the Function underneath is called:

```
sucess = ReadContract(cFile.ParentFolder.Path & Application.PathSeparator, cFile.ShortName, dWorkbook)
```

Before this call, the dWorkbook has been created by a short separate function.

Below function readContracts runs throught all wanted workbooks in the subfolder and copies them to dWorkbook. When the last file in subfolder has been read dWorkbook is saved and closed, so one aggregated workbook per subfolder.

The macro runs throught and sucessfully copies all 4.200 files stored in subfolders, all good.
However, in course of the execution excel consumes with practically each loop of the function more memory and ends shortly before finalisation at 1,5 GB which is lowering the execution speed.

But why?

Isnt the memory freed up after exit from the function? The workbook in which the data are copied into gets saved and closed after each subfolder. In total 39 workbooks are created consuming 68 MB disk space so even they all would stay open during execution they cannot explain the memory usage of excel jumping up to 1,5 GB.

The soucefiles (contracts) the data are copied from are 2,8 MB each so this could explain but they are not opened and just the data are extracted via the formula. Any memory allocation / variable lifetime should expire after leaving the function or not?

Is there anything wrong within my code why my macro is eating so much RAM?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

```
Function ReadContract(cPath As String, cFile As String, ByRef dWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean 'dWorkbook As Workbook
On Error GoTo NoSheetInFile
    Dim lRowUsed     As Integer
    'Dim HasSheet     As Variant
    Dim dynamicRange As String
    Dim contractCheck As Variant
    Dim commaInName As Integer
    Dim splitName As Variant
    Dim formula As String

    ' checks sheet "Auslesen" exists in the workbook to take data from
    contractCheck = CheckSheetExists(cPath, cFile, nameSheet)

    If contractCheck = False Then 'if sheet doesnt exist, end Function and continue with next file
    
        ReadContract = False
        Exit Function
    
    End If

    ' last row with data in the new WB
    lRowUsed = dWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' creates a dynamic range with last row with data +1 as starting point
    dynamicRange = "A" & lRowUsed + 1 & ":" & maxCol & lRowUsed + rowsToRead
    
    commaInName = InStr(1, cFile, "'", vbTextCompare)

    If commaInName <> 0 Then
    
        splitName = Split(cFile, "'", -1, vbTextCompare)
        
        formula = "='" & cPath & "[" & splitName(0) & "''" & splitName(1) & "]" & nameSheet & "'!" & sCell & ""
    
    Else
    
        ' copies data from closed source WB
        formula = "='" & cPath & "[" & cFile & "]" & nameSheet & "'!" & sCell & ""
    
    End If
    
        With dWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(dynamicRange)
            .formula = formula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        
    Call CleanUp(lRowUsed, dWorkbook) 'cleans some unneeded rows which been copied as copying all in once easier than copying row 3-4, 6, 9-10 separately
    
    ' when execution successful till here
    ReadContract = True
    Exit Function
NoSheetInFile:
ReadContract = False
    
End Function
```

Comment: Are you emptying any large arrays, dictionaries, etc. when they're not needed or at least at the end of script execution?  Btw, nothing looks bad in the function you wrote but it appears that's just a small fraction of the code.

Comment: In fact no. But there arent really large once. THe dynamic range is just a relatively short string as well as the formula string. The "intense" Copy/execution part takes place in the With block, which I assume gets disposed when finish.

Comment: 1.Working in Excel is always going to take longer and consume more memory(?) vs storing the data in memory and transferring it.  Is it possible to store the data from the `formula` in an array and write that to your `dWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(dynamicRange)` instead of creating these many formulas across the workbooks?  2. What is the point of the line `.Value = .Value` in your `With` block?  Does this do some kind of "refresh"?

Comment: I'm not sure it's documented when and if Excel closes the workbooks it had to implicitly open to calculate an external formula. The external formulas you are using are relatively pointless as they do not calculate anything and you are replacing them with values immediately anyway. So the first thing to try would be to stop copying via external formulas and start copying via manually opening the other workbook, copying and closing it.

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor `.Value = .Value` replaces the formulas in the cells with the values they have produced.

Comment: @GSerg why the external formulas are pointless? They are used to extract the data out of the closed workbooks and .value = .value is as you also wrote just putting the values instead of the formulas.

Comment: @Alex, If you are essentially copying values from workbooks, why do you need the formulas?  I believe that is why GSerg is saying they're pointless.

Comment: The source files the data are coming from are each relatively large, have macros inside and need time to open. Before we had a macro opening them and copying which was an overnight task for 4.200 files. now by extracting the data via formula execution time for 4.200 files went down to 30-40 min depending network traffic. Just to underline, the marco does its job, I'm just wondering for the excessive memory consumption. The sole use of the formula string construction is to retrieve the data without need to open the respective source workbook.

Comment: You cannot retrieve the data without opening the file, can you, so the file is still opened, you just don't get to see it. If the original approach did not consume that kind of memory, it's even more likely this is the reason. When opening files with code, you can both prohibit any macros from running and disable screen updating and calculations in those files. If you don't want to do that, try disabling calculations in `dWorkbook`, leave it with formulas, and only in the very end calculate them all manually, save and close `dWorkbook`, along with its Excel instance.

Comment: thanks @GSerg. This must be the reason. even based on formulas likely the source WB is opened in background as you said without seeing it when code is running. However, the macro is running fine. And yes could instead open the source WB as read-only and with marcos deactivated. Thanks.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but as a solution you could consider combining this data using Power Query instead of VBA

Comment: You mean like using ADO?

Comment: He meant [Power Query](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/). It can be used in Excel to load data and transform it. You can combine different sources. In the toolbar, go to Data -> Get Data -> From file -> From folder. There you can load all files in a folder. If it does not work, load them one by one and combine the tables later in the Power Query editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine all workbooks in a directory in PowerQuery using below. Not sure if that helps. I've never run into a memory issue doing that

In powerquery, change code below to reflect path, then paste into home...advanced editor....

then file ... close and load ... back into Excel

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\directory\subdirectory"), 
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),  
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),   
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),    
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}), 
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),    
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)   
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Did this answer help at all? If so, please upvote and then accept it as solution